# How to print only one message for different results

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I have this code and I'm trying to print only one message with all the results, but instead is printing each message with the result which is getting awful.

```
a = int(input('First Integer: '))
b = int(input('Second Integer: '))
if a < b:
    for i in range(a, b + 1):
        print('The Numbers in Ascending Order Are: ', i)
else:
    for i in range(a, b - 1, -1):
        print('The Numbers in Descending Order Are: ', i)
```

Comment: Hello, please refer to [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are having issues with the basic understanding of loops in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid repeating the message, take it out of the for loop, like this:

```
a = int(input("First Integer:"))
b = int(input("Second Integer:"))
if (a < b):
    print("The numbers in ascending order are:")
    for number in range(a, b + 1):
        print(number)
else:
    print("The numbers in descending order are:")
    for number in range(a, b - 1, -1):
        print(number)
```

Sample outputs:

```
First Integer:5
Second Integer:2
The numbers in descending order are:
5
4
3
2

First Integer:2
Second Integer:4
The numbers in ascending order are:
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks @tandotburn That's all I was looking for. it's not changing my code, which is the best thing, it is also printing the numbers inclusively and in columns. Simple and easy

Answer (score 2):

Don't print each item in a loop then.

Write instead.

**Code**

```
a = int(input('First Integer: '))
b = int(input('Second Integer: '))
if a < b:
  print(f'The Numbers in Ascending Order Are: {list(range(a, b+1))}')

else:
  print(f'The Numbers in Descending Order Are: {list(range(a, b-1, -1))}')
```

**Output**

[image]

[image]

**Another approach with for loop**

```
a = int(input('First Integer: '))
b = int(input('Second Integer: '))
if a < b:
  temp = []
  for i in range(a, b + 1):
    temp.append(i)
  print('The Numbers in Ascending Order Are: ', temp)
else:
  temp = []
  for i in range(a, b - 1, -1):
    temp.append(i)
  print('The Numbers in Descending Order Are: ', temp)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: This one was really close to what I'm doing, but I'm wondering if I had a problem without the for loop

Comment: The only way you were deviating from your expected outcome using a loop is that you were printing each item every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Added another approach with `for` loop for you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, print the order message before each `for` loop. Secondly, you can use `range` in the following way:

```
a = int(input('First Integer: '))
b = int(input('Second Integer: '))

if a < b:
    print('The Numbers in Ascending Order Are: ')
    for i in range(a,b + 1): # adding 1 to include b
        print(i)
else:
    print('The Numbers in Descending Order Are:')
    for i in range(a , b - 1, -1): # reducing 1 to include b
        print(i)
```

Input:

```
First Integer: 1
Second Integer: 5
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Input:

```
First Integer: 5
Second Integer: 1
```

Output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: This one I like it but is not  Printing all numbers from A to B inclusively,

Comment: @AndresGuevaraAguirre oh I didn't understand you want to print all the numbers from A to B (it does make more sense..). I'll edit the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort them:

```
a = int(input("First Integer"))
b = int(input("Second Integer"))
c = [a,b]
if a < b:
  sorted(c)
else:
  sorted(c,reverse=True)
```

Comment: First time I see the sorted () function

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your second loop and each message should be issued with the result of the loop instead of per item.

```
a = int(input('First Integer: '))
b = int(input('Second Integer: '))
asc = ", ".join([str(i) for i in range(a, b + 1)])
desc = ", ".join([str(i) for i in range(b, a - 1, -1)])

if a < b:
    print(f'The Numbers in Ascending Order Are: {asc}')
    print(f'The Numbers in Descending Order Are: {desc}')
```

Comment: I need the for loop. This one is printing both, Ascending and Descending Order